# just a hidden error

Tags: php

hello 
i have this code in php

---

```
> <form name ="deleteForm"
> action="CRUD/deleteAct.php"
> method="POST"><input type="text"
> value="'.$row['id'].'"/><input
> type="submit" value="DELETE" /></form>
```

---

and when it post to deleteAct.php
we have this code to get the id value

connection..

```
mysql_select_db('bena');
echo "delete info";
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo "$id";
$delete = "DELETE FROM activites WHERE id = $id";

$delquy = mysql_query($delete,$connection);
if( $delquy )
echo " information was deleted!";
```

i was exchanged $_POST with $_GET in the deletAct.php file but didn't solve!

Comment: Might be a good idea to read up on the topic of "SQL injection" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial form uses the POST method, hence if you need the value of id, look in the $_POST array. Generally, it might be nice to sanitise the value anyway. It needs a name attribute though:

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/> 

//..

mysql_select_db('bena');
echo "delete info";
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
echo "$id";
$delete = "DELETE FROM activites WHERE id = $id";

$delquy = mysql_query($delete,$connection);
if( $delquy )
echo " information was deleted!";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
```

You haven't given this a name.

Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="id" />
```

and make sure you're picking up `$id = $_POST['id'];` at the other page.

Also, as said in the comments, read up on SQL injection. And look at PDO too:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Answer (score 1):

Your input filed dosen't have a name

it should be

```
<input type="text" name="id" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>
```

Also, to prevent injections

```
$delete = "DELETE FROM activites WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."";
```

or use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)